# EditorFor ignores tabindex. How do you set a tabindex?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper, tabindex, editorfor

The use of tabindex seems to only work for htmlhelpers like Textboxfor and not EditorFor

For example;

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.MyItem, new { @tabindex = "3" })%>
```

Produces a tabindex value.

However, if you use;

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => Model.MyItem, new { @tabindex = "3" })%>
```

Then the result is that the control is created as expected, but the tabindex is missing.

So...... How is it possible to set the tabindex for a given EditorFor control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem I was having is that I needed to create a EditorFor type mechanism in order to format the decimal like a currency (our system has multiple currencies so "C" would not have been appropriate), get a tab index working AND allow the system to maintain the standard validation.

I've managed to achieve that using the following. By creating my own custom editor control.

Create a file (mine is called decimal.ascx) within the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates directory of your project.

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<decimal?>" %>
 <% int intTabindex = 0;
   decimal myVal = 0;

   string strModelValue = "";
   if (Model != null)
   {
       myVal = (decimal)Model;
       strModelValue = myVal.ToString("#.00");
   }
   else
       strModelValue = "";



   if (ViewData["tabindex"] != null)
   {
       intTabindex = (int)ViewData["tabindex"];
   }
 %>
 <%: Html.TextBox("", strModelValue, new { @tabindex = intTabindex })%>
```

Essentially, this code just overrides what would normally be presented in a "decimal" EditorFor method with the;

```
<%: Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("#.00"), new { @tabindex = intTabindex }) %>
```

template.

My calling code now reads;

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => Model.MyItem, new { tabindex = 5 })%>
```

The result is the following code on the page.

```
<input id="Model_MyItem" name="Model.MyItem" tabindex="5" type="text" value="12.33" />
```

Which is exactly what I required.

Whilst this is only true for my particular circumstances, I would encourage anybody looking to solve this issue to attempt a custom control first for the task as it might save you a considerable amount of time.

If would of course be possible in the code to create a specific type of control required and adjust the results around that.

For example; we could simple add another item in the call to determine the text format.

```
new {tabindex = 12, numberformat=2}
```

Then simply create a handler for all the formats.

Answer (score 1):

Since the EditorFor is just a template for a DataType it's only expecting a datatype as it's Model.  There are a couple of ways of going about this I am guessing.  You could possibly add the tabindex to an anonymous object that will be merged into the ViewData for the EditorTemplate like so.

Code in your View:

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.Username, "test", new { tabindex = 3, style = "width: 400px;" })
```

EditorForModel Template Check for ViewData:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, ViewData)%>
```

This should render an text input with a tabindex of 3 and style="width: 400px;"

Happy coding.

Edited:
Here is exactly the markup I have inside of my test page:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.DollarsAmount, "NullableDecimal", new { tabindex = 99 }) %>
```

I'm telling the EditorFor template to select the "NullableDecimal" EditorTemplate that I have created. (You could place a UiHint attribute on the property inside of the model also to tell it what editortemplate to use)

"NullableDecimal" EditorTemplate located in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<decimal?>" %>

<%: Html.TextBox(string.Empty, (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("#.00") : null), ViewData) %>
```

What's more extensible about my implementation is the extra ViewData that I pass in via my anonymous object is merged into the ViewData dictionary to be used by the EditorTemplate.  So if you don't pass any ViewData in to the EditorTemplate then it wont render your text inputs tabindex to 0 as your implementation currently will do.  Plus your implementation will only account for tabindexes and not for any other input attributes. i.e. maxlength or style

Comment: Sorry, maybe there is something amiss in my MVC installation. But while it "should" render OK, it doesn't. Using either tabindex or @tabindex or ="3" or =3; I do not get a tabindex rendered with the control. Did you check to see if this works before submitting the answer?

Comment: I have just created a totally new application to test my theory and on my installation at least, I cannot add tabindex to an EditorFor control. Can you please create a new MVC 2 application and simply edit the logon page, please confirm that if you add new {tabindex = 3} and changed the TextBoxfor to EditorFor that tabindex appears in the page source. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I did test this code inside of an Asp.net Mvc 2 project.  The anonymous object will only contain element attributes that will be used to supply to the method that accepts an IDictionary<string, object> html attributes for the Html.TextBoxFor

Comment: I'm not sure why the tabindex did not come through for you because I have tested this in Asp.net Mvc 2 and 3 with my implementation for the EditorFor and this has worked.  I'm sure you know that you can either set the template to lookup on either the model property with the UiHint attribute or by passing the templatename in with the EditorFor call in your source.  Mine is a more extensible since it will merge any extra attributes you want for that rendering of the textbox.

Comment: -1 because could have never been working, neighter in version 2 or 3.

Comment: +1 Knowing this is a very old post, thought I would add that `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.text, new {tabindex = "1" })` works in MVC4. Looks like they fixed this to work as expected.

Comment: @christophersw thanks for this comment.  I was finding all these posts saying it wasn't possible, but as we're using MVC5 we're good :)